# printing all words in a trie tree in java which exists in a tree from previous insertions

Tags: java, depth-first-search, trie

Ok. I was trying to print all the words in my trie tree which their (endOfWord) were true but all I found from searching on the internet was printing all the words that are possible to make.  Here is my code in java:

```
public class Trie {
    static final int ALPHABETS_SIZE = 11;
    static int counter = 0;
    static class TrieNode {
        TrieNode[] children;
        boolean isEndOfWord;

        TrieNode() {
            isEndOfWord = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABETS_SIZE; i++) {
                children[i] = null;
            }
        }

        static TrieNode root;

        static void insert(String key) {
            int level;
            int length = key.length();
            int index;
            counter++;
            TrieNode pCrawl = root;

            for (level = 0; level < length; level++) {
                if (key.charAt(level) == 'A') {
                    index = 11;
                } else {
                    index = key.charAt(level) - '0';
                }

                if (pCrawl.children[index] == null)
                    pCrawl.children[index] = new TrieNode();

                pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index];
            }
            pCrawl.isEndOfWord = true;
        }
    }

    public static void print(){

    }
}
```

the whole strings that are going to be added to the trie are like this :
A1A23A541A0 or A388A1
I hope somebody could answer me how to do this using DFS algorithm.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does above code even work? Without initializing childrens, you are setting values?

Comment: i haven't initialized it yet but i will do it in my main function later . i just need a way for printing them correctly

Comment: That's a huge chunk of code you posted there! Maybe you could only include the parts of the code in your post where you think it goes wrong?

Comment: Ok Sacha i changed it

Comment: The requirement is not clear to me. Please explain and add test data and expected result.